# Symfony - How to handle received file via PHP form upload

Tags: php, forms, file, symfony

I have to write a controller that receives a CSV file. When I POST the file via Postman, I know how to handle the file in Symfony:

```
    if ($this->getRequest()->files) {
        $filename = date('Ymd').'-filename.csv';
        $directory = $this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/';
        $request = $this->get('request');
        $data = $request->getContent(); 
    }
```

If the file is uploaded via a PHP form upload like this:

```
    <form action="{{path('import_csv_file')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     Select file to upload:
     <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
     <input type="submit" value="Upload CSV File" name="submit">
    </form>
```

How can I handle the file in the controller?
Thanks!

Comment: U say "I know how to handle the file in Symfony" and "How can I handle the file in the controller?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your files are stored in $request. Is an array if you sent multiple files and is an UploadedFile(); if file is just one. The array is an UploadedFile() collection.

```
public function yourAction(Request $request)
{
    $file = $request->files;
}
```